# Custom url scheme not recognized in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

My Android app has a WebView, in this WebView I want to load some local files via JavaScript (parsing a .csv from within the app files).

To make this possible, I tried implementing a custom url scheme as recommended by others answers on StackOverflow.

```java
private static class CustomWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String url = request.getUrl().toString();
        if (url.startsWith("myscheme:///")) {
            String newUrl = url.replace("myscheme:///", "file:///android_asset/");
            webView.loadUrl(newUrl);
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("myscheme:///")) {
            String newUrl = url.replace("myscheme:///", "file:///android_asset/");
            webView.loadUrl(newUrl);
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```

However when I run some JavaScript in WebView like: `fetch('myscheme:///data.csv')` I get the error message `Fetch API cannot load myscheme:///cards.csv. URL scheme "myscheme" is not supported.`

Is this a limitation of the fetch API, or am I doing something wrong in my implementation of the custom WebView? I also tried `XMLHttpRequest`, but received an error about `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///android_asset/data.csv' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy`.

Comment: Javascript doesn't change the url of the page so in think your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` doesn't called